# Desktop Multithreading UI sample application for .net

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, multithreading, user-interface

Are there any good sample UI applications which illustrate multi threading best practices in .net?

The scenario I am thinking of is a graphically rich scorecard where the kpi's are being updated from several different sources and threads.

Although I am interested in WPF a Winforms sample application would I believe serve just as well as they are both single-threaded apartment based.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google is your friend :)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/AlternateMultithreadedGUI.aspx

http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/charliesears/archive/2008/07/23/multithreading-in-c.aspx

a lot of examples here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Articles/ArticleListing.aspx?SectionID=1&SubSectionID=149

Comment: thanks - some interesting reading. Not sure if these are best practices but I will check them out.

Comment: I have voted you up also, I will keep the question open for a while  to see if there are any further responses. Thanks